# Am I using passing my argument correctly with ref?

Tags: c#, keyword, ref

```
SMSCOMMS SMSEngine = new SMSCOMMS("COM6");
```

The code doesn't seem to take my argument of `COM6` as a valid `ref string`.How can I solve this?

```
public class SMSCOMMS
{
   public SMSCOMMS(ref string COMMPORT)
   {
    SMSPort = new SerialPort();
    SMSPort.PortName = COMMPORT;
    SMSPort.BaudRate = 9600;
    SMSPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    SMSPort.DataBits = 8;
    SMSPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    SMSPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
    SMSPort.DtrEnable = true;
    SMSPort.RtsEnable = true;
    SMSPort.NewLine = System.Environment.NewLine;
    ReadThread = new Thread(
        new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ReadPort));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a temporary with `ref`, because the called method must be able to assign to the caller's variable.  Why are you using it to begin with?  You never assign to `COMMPORT`.

Why not just:

```
public SMSCOMMS(string COMMPORT)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to pass a `ref` param unless you're intending to modify the actual variable the caller's passed.  Since you *can't* modify a string literal (it's constant, by definition), it's not valid for passing by reference.

Comment: Wrong.  You can use `ref` with strings, and there are cases when you want to. If the method assigns to the `ref` variable, the caller now has a reference to a different string in their own variable.

Comment: I didn't say string -- i said string *literal*.  If you know of a way to modify a string literal, let the .net people know about it, cause it's probably a bug.  By definition, literals are constant.  "a" will never be anything but "a".  Though it could be replaced by another string, that is not the same thing as modifying the string itself.

Comment: Add to that, the code in question obviously was passing a string literal, not a variable (read: *there's no variable to assign to*), which i *thought* was obvious, and you have the reason stuff broke.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `ref` when you are passing something that has a usable reference. That means you have to declare a variable first, then pass that variable by ref:

```
string comm = "COM6";
SMSCOMMS SMSEngine = new SMSCOMMS(ref comm);
```